# java.io.IOException: Premature EOF while downloading pdf over https

Tags: java, http, io, stream

I get an error when trying to download a pdf with java. I know there are similar questions, but not as specific as mine.

My code snippet:

```
URL url = new URL("https://.../abc.pdf");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
... 
InputStream in= conn.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4096);
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Ther servers response header:

```
 X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
 Transfer-Encoding:chunked
 Date:Thu 26 Apr 2012 12:07:59 GMT
 Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=abc.pdf
 Set-Cookie:Language=en-gb; path=/
 Connection:Keep-Alive
 Content-Type:application/octet-stream
 Server:Microsoft-IIS/6.0
 X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
 Cache-Control:private
```

The exception (at `in.read(buf)`):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:556)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:600)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:687)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2959)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2953)
```

The code works for almost all cases and had been used thousands of times. But in very rare cases I get this exception. But I can download the pdf with the browser. Also if I put the pdf on my own server I can download it with my code. So it must have something todo with the way the server serves this pdf.

Maybe it has something to do with the `Transfer-Encoding:chunked`?

Has anybody an idea, what I can try to get this fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems a bug related to java chunked handling. Many solved by reading one byte at a time and put the read in a try-catch for EOFException.

Comment: I just tried settign the buffer size to 1: `byte[] buf = new byte[1];` but the same exception occurs. I will try the try catch now.

Comment: It actually works if I ignore the exception, the stream is still fully loaded. Even with a bigger buffer. Thank you for the hint! Do you think it might cause a problem in some cases if the buffer is not 1? Can I rely on just ignoring the exception?

Comment: If the bug occurs in the first chunk only(as I suppose): no problem, just ignore exception. In general: yes.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I added another condition to make sure I only ignore this case: `e.getMessage().equals("Premature EOF") && e.getStackTrace().length > 0 && e.getStackTrace()[0].toString().indexOf("sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking") >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should need this code.

```
try {
}catch(IOException e) {
} finally {
   try {
     if (in != null)
      in.close();
   }catch(Exception e) {
   }
}
```

or try use IOUtils.close in Apache Library.

```
   finally {
     IOUtils.close(in);
   }
```

I had a same happen. but fixed it now.